# Creating distinct serialno on unique "product numbers"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
StgID---|---ItemNumber

1            0034
2            0035  
3            0036
4            0036
5            0036
6            0058
```

And I need a way to assign some sort of unique item number for each row where it would look like this:

```
StgID---|---ItemNumber--|--SerialID

1            0034             1
2            0035             2
3            0036             3
4            0036             3
5            0036             3
6            0058             4
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ItemNumber) SerialId
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```